# Rewrite cond in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^Therapists/(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ Therapist/city.php?value1=$1
```

- how to create pattern for United-States
- i.e **abcdef-abcdef** 6 chars before `-` and 6 chars after `-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want exactly 6 characters before the **-** and after use `{6}`, if you want 1-6 characters, use `{1,6}`. In general for min to max characters modify the rule below to useuse `{min, max}`.

```
RewriteRule ^Therapists/(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{6})-([a-zA-Z0-9_]{6}))$ Therapist/city.php?value1=$1
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^Therapists/(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,6})-([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,6}))$ Therapist/city.php?value1=$1
```

Etc.